# Django memcache expire url

Tags: django-1.8, python-memcached, django-caching

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.utils.cache import get_cache_key

def expire_page(path):
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.path = path
    key = get_cache_key(request)
    if cache.has_key(key):   
        cache.delete(key)
```

Using memcached in django to clear a url from cache.The request seems cached.get_cache_key doesn't return the key.

Settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.